# How to set my resources location of Xcode project

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a project that it's folder as below:

[image]

And in main.cpp I want to read the file "a.lua" ,but the result is the error that "No such file or floder". And I know the reason is "a.lua" not exist in Products folder after compile.

[image]

I want to know how to solve this problem with out change the Products' location or put the "a.lua" into Products by myself. Is there some configuration of build or compile to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Copy Files build phase to copy the Lua files to a specific location when building your project. You can access your project's build phases by selecting the project from the project navigator on the left side of the project window. Click the Build Phases button at the top of the editor. Use the Destination menu to pick the location to copy the files. The Products Directory is one of the options.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, command-line tool projects have a Copy Files build phase. It initially copies a file with the extension .1 to an absolute path. To add the Lua files to something other than an absolute path, you will have to add another Copy Files build phase to the project. Choose Editor > Add Build Phase > Add Copy Files Build Phase. If the menu is disabled, click the disclosure triangle next to the existing Copy Files build phase, like in the screenshot, and click inside the build phase. The menus to add a build phase in a command-line tool project were disabled for me unless I clicked inside an existing build phase.